# In circuit 2S Lithium Charging

Tags: charger, lithium

I'm designing a board with a micro that controls a hobby servo. The circuit is usually powered from 12VDC but may be disconnected at any point, thus we have 2 lithium cells in series providing ~7.4V that will run the servo(which pulls substantial current maybe ~2A) and a small LDO 5V regulator for the micro. What I'm looking for is a lithium charger IC that will charge and balance the two cells (ofc I can't charge the 2cells in series, which is dangerous, thus I need a balance circuit that is connected to each individual cell) while the external 12VDC is connected. Can anyone recommend anything? Can I run the circuit off the cells always and just use the 12V to charge the cells when connected?

Comment: Perhaps you could share references to the ICs you have considered, both charge/monitor ICs, and online charge ICs if any. This will help others to avoid covering ground you have already researched, and / or contribute their own knowledge on those parts.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of LiIon charger ICs that claim to adequately manage the charging of two LiIon cells in series with no centre tap connection to the battery.

The below referenced Microchip IC is an example - their presumption seems to be that balancing for a 2sS battery is not needed.

This IC was chosen on the basis of meeting 2S spec, being in stock at Digikey and being about their cheapest offering - not always the optimum way to choose ICs :-)

The IC is the MCP73841/2/3/4 - [**Datasheet here**](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21823D.pdf).

This IC uses an external MOSFET for charging control and a 100 mV sense resistor with 100 mV drop at target current. 1A example circuits are given but a 100 mA or 10A charger could be equally well implemented.

Only claimed differences are xxx1 & 2 have thermal monitor and 3/4 do not, and 1 & 2 are for 1 x LiIon cell and 3/4 are for dual LiIon cells.

No obvious difference in general functionality is present between the 1 & 2 cell versions.

A reasonably good skim through the datasheet does not turn up any mention of cell balancing. Microchip almost always seem to 'know their stuff' - their presumption seems to be that balancing for a 2sS battery is not needed.